# tarantula error: uninitialized constant Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-crawler

When I run:

```
rake tarantula:test
```

I got these errors:

```
warning: parser/current is loading parser/ruby21, which recognizes
warning: 2.1.4-compliant syntax, but you are running 2.1.2.
rm -rf tmp/tarantula
/usr/local/bin/ruby -I"lib:test" -I"/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.1/lib" "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.1/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/tarantula/**/*_test.rb" 
Run options: 

# Running tests:

[1/1] TarantulaTest#test_tarantula = 0.00 s
  1) Error:
TarantulaTest#test_tarantula:
NameError: uninitialized constant Rails
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/tarantula-rails3-0.3.3/lib/relevance/tarantula.rb:26:in `rails_root'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/tarantula-rails3-0.3.3/lib/relevance/tarantula/rails_integration_proxy.rb:15:in `rails_integration_test'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/tarantula-rails3-0.3.3/lib/relevance/core_extensions/test_case.rb:12:in `tarantula_crawler'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/tarantula-rails3-0.3.3/lib/relevance/core_extensions/test_case.rb:7:in `tarantula_crawl'
    /beesor/test/tarantula/tarantula_test.rb:26:in `test_tarantula'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/minitest/unit.rb:1265:in `run'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit/testcase.rb:17:in `run'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:36:in `block in run'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__906851432856568922__setup__2846572471353198287__callbacks'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_setup_callbacks'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:35:in `run'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/minitest/unit.rb:940:in `block in _run_suite'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/minitest/unit.rb:933:in `map'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/minitest/unit.rb:933:in `_run_suite'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:663:in `block in _run_suites'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:661:in `each'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:661:in `_run_suites'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/minitest/unit.rb:884:in `_run_anything'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/minitest/unit.rb:1092:in `run_tests'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/minitest/unit.rb:1079:in `block in _run'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/minitest/unit.rb:1078:in `each'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/minitest/unit.rb:1078:in `_run'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/minitest/unit.rb:1066:in `run'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:27:in `run'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:780:in `run'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:372:in `block (2 levels) in autorun'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:33:in `run_once'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:371:in `block in autorun'

Finished tests in 0.031650s, 31.5959 tests/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips

ruby -v: ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux]
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [ruby -I"lib:test" -I"/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.1/lib" "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.2.1/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/tarantula/**/*_test.rb" ]

Tasks: TOP => tarantula_test
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

And it is my simple **test_tarantula.rb file**:

```
require "relevance/tarantula"

class TarantulaTest < ActionController::IntegrationTest

  def test_tarantula    
    t = tarantula_crawl(self)
  end

end
```

What is the meaning of **uninitialized constant Rails** error?

Any idea?

Comment: It probably means in your  `Rakefile` that the environment is not loaded. What does that task look like?

Comment: how do I load the rails environment with tarantula? I just follow this simple example (https://github.com/relevance/tarantula)

Comment: Is `rails` in your `Gemfile`?

Comment: `gem 'rails', '3.2.17'`

Comment: If you've done a `bundle install` that should work. Maybe `require "rails"` in your `Rakefile` could help fix it.